# hide back, home and recents apps button in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Libgdx shows these buttons by default. Is it possible to hide them and show them only when user slides with finger down(I think this is how unity has done it)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide virtual Android buttons (on the phones that do not have physical buttons :) ) you have to set the application to use the [Immersive Full-Screen mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html).

You can achieve this by setting proper flags from **android.view.View** method by adding this code in your **AndroidLauncher** class

```
    @TargetApi(19)
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
```

[Take a look at this tutorial](http://www.pixnbgames.com/blog/libgdx/how-to-hide-virtual-buttons-in-android-libgdx/) to get more information.

Comment: Great! Just for future readers, these are the constants that do the trick: View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION

Comment: Simply `config.useImmersiveMode = true;` should be enough. https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplicationConfiguration.html#useImmersiveMode

Answer (score 2):

Instead of overriding android methods you can enable option in AndroidApplicationConfiguration

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    config.useImmersiveMode = true;  // libgdx will handle it

    initialize(new Main(), config);
}
```